# Do I need to copy paste my navigation bar code on each page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

so when I create a multi-page Website do I need to copy and paste the navbar, footer, etc. on each and every page, or is there a technology or method to do this quicker and more efficiently?

Comment: You could use something like Jinja2 for templates (I use it as part of Flask), or something like React for components.

Comment: Mostly, try using the same stylesheet so it would be easier maybe?

Comment: You could look at static site generators such as eleventy or hugo. There isnt really a good way to natively include html snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are, and that technology is called framework. For example in Laravel (php back-end framework) you can use blade directives to include pieces of code in a view.

### For example

> In one of my projects the home view source code (php file) looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    
    @include('sections/head')
    @include('sections/navbar')
    @include('sections/home_body')
    @include('sections/footer')

</html>
```

As you can see I do not need to copy paste the same code all the time. I just use the blade directive `@include()`

This is just one example, I suggest you explore and read about all the different frameworks. For PHP the one I recommend is Laravel and it's not difficult to learn.

Read a little bit about good frameworks here: https://hackr.io/blog/web-development-frameworks. And choose the one the best fits your needs. Frameworks will help you tons, they all have plenty of tools to empower your coding.

Comment: **Frameworks** might be a broad solution to this question since frameworks are pre-written code that can be utilized for **variety** of usecases. What if someone has to do this with vanilla JavaScript?